# arduino boards manager configuration

Tags: c++, arduino-due, compile

I installed the Arduino IDE 1.6.4, and used the "boards manager" to install the package for Arduino Due.

I am using c++11 in my project so i need to add the `compiler.cpp.extra_flags=-std=gnu++11` like i did in the `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/platform.txt` file (i am on MacOSX).
It seems that arduino is ignoring that file and using a configuration coming from somewhere else.

Where is the downloaded package installed? Can it be configured?

Comment: Did you try looking under where the preferences file is stored?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you are right, there it is, in the packages folder. Write it as an answer and you will get the accept points!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams suggested: the configuration files for the plugins can be found in the Arduino ide preferences directory. Click the menu Arduino->Preferences (under macosx) at the bottom of the window there is the clickable path of the `preferences.txt` file. In the same folder as that file you will find a `packages` folder, where the plugins are downloaded.